# Visual Studio remote debugging application hosted on Linux - unable to enumerate running instances of the CoreCLR in the specific process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug remotely an application that's being hosted on Linux

**"Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"**

with

**.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.500)**

I'm connecting via Visual Studio via **SSH**

and I've tried both modes:

- Managed .NET Core for Unix
- Native (GDB)

Project has been compiled on Windows

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release -r linux-x64
```

and also

```
dotnet publish --configuration Debug -r linux-x64
```

and works perfectly fine, but for some reason I'm receiving:

**Managed .NET Core for Unix**:

**Fail to attach to process: Unable to enumerate running instances of the CoreCLR in the specific process**

---

And if that's relevant (probably not, because other people use **Managed .NET Core for Unix** for that)

**Native (GDB)**:
**Unable to start debugging. Unable to estabilish a connection to GDB. Debug output may containt more information**

debug information:

```
Starting unix command: 'gdb --interpreter=mi'
bash: gdb: command not found
gdb --interpreter=mi exited with code 127.
```

---

In Visual Studio process is listed as:

```
Process: MyProjectName

Title: /home/deploy/app/MyProjectName StartUpArgument
```

Anybody has an idea what can cause that?

You can see how people do that with Raspberry Pi here:

https://youtu.be/ySzTCl-H10w?t=955

Comment: what kind of remote application it is?

Comment: @kennyzx WebApplication / MVC

Comment: And what is the name of the process you are trying to attach to?

Comment: @kennyzx ``Process: MyProjectName`` +

``Title:/home/deploy/app/MyProjectName StartUpArgument``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently our stupidity is limitless

We've been running our app as a service but `FROM OTHER USER ACCOUNT THAN WAS USED IN SSH`

Connecting to process works properly, but for some reason

`Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document`

edit:

Solution:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97445/vs2017-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no.html

I also checked:

Enable source link support

Fall back to git credential manager auth. for all source link requests

Enable source server support
Enable just my code [OFF]

Answer (score 1):

## What ste

## Step 1

[image]

## Step 2

[image]

## Step 3

[image]

## Step 4

[image]

## Step 5

[image]

Comment: did you try connect by private key