# Is it possible to setup Visual Studio 2017 such that it runs and debugs a .NET Core C# application on remote Linux machine instead of local machine?

Tags: c#, linux, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

My scenario is that I have Visual Studio 2017 running on Windows and all the sources are stored locally on the same Windows machine and I want that code to be shipped to a remote Linux machine, compiled there, run there and remote debugged there.

With proper configuration I can create a CMake C++ project and have it run and remote debugged on remote Linux machine right out of the box. Can I have the same for a .NET Core project with C# code?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946525/visual-studio-remote-debugging-application-hosted-on-linux-unable-to-enumerate) which implies that I could run `dotnet publish` and maybe also use "attach to process" then but that doesn't look  a straightforward as just selecting a startup item and clicking "Play" in a CMake project.

Can I have the same experience of remote starting and debugging my C# code on remote Linux machine as it works in case of CMake C++ projects in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I have the same experience of remote starting and debugging my C#
>   code on remote Linux machine as it works in case of CMake C++ projects
>   in Visual Studio 2017?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. For now, the remote-debugging experience in **Linux** for `.net core` is quite different from that for `C++`. It would be a bit more complex when configuring remote debugging in Linux for .net core projects.

You can't simply select the startup item and click "play" like what you did in CMake C++ projects.

Instead you do need to configure the `Attach to Process` in VS after you start the .net core application in **Linux** .(`dotnet publish` command is not necessary, you can use the **Publish** option in VS, and then *copy the output publish directory to a directory with execute permission on the Linux Test VM*)

Assuming the `.net core` you mentioned above indicates `asp.net core`, please check [Debugging ASP Core on Linux with Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/debugging-asp-core-on-linux-with-visual-studio-2017/) for more details about how to configure the environment to get a start. Hope it helps :)